# Ascii code to write sri in tamil keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard, ascii, tamil

I would like to write `ksh` and `sri` using a Tamil keyboard.
It would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide the ASCII value for both?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have a ascii code, they aren't ascii letters.  They do have a unicode value, which is what you need.  The unicode charts for tamil are found here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script  I'd tell you the value, but I can't read it.

Comment: i m making a tamil keyboard in android.. i've given the label of shri and ksha but what m i suppose to write in the 'android:codes="" ' field???

Answer (score 0):

Under `android:codes` you got to write the code of the character.

Example: Character - `௧`
Code is `U+0BE7`

Convert the `0BE7` to decimal. The decimal value you get is to be put under the `android:codes="3047"`